# boost::spirit::karma alternative selection based on properties of the input

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma

I'm trying to write a boost::spirit::karma generator where some of the output depends on non-trivial properties of the input values.

The actual problem is part of a larger grammar, but this example has the same properties as several of the other troublesome rules and is actually one of the grammar rules that is causing me trouble.

I'll start with a minimal example that is almost what I want, and then work from there.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename OutputIterator_T>
struct Test_Grammar :
  boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIterator_T, std::vector<double>()>
{
  Test_Grammar() : Test_Grammar::base_type(start), start(), value()
    {
      namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

      start
        = *(value % karma::lit(", "))
        ;

      value
        = (karma::double_)
        ;
    }

  boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator_T, std::vector<double>()> start;
  boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator_T, double()> value;
};

template <typename OutputIterator_T>
bool generate_output(OutputIterator_T& sink, std::vector<double> const& data)
{
  Test_Grammar<OutputIterator_T> grammar;
  return (boost::spirit::karma::generate(sink, grammar, data));
}

int main (int, char**)
{
  std::string generated;
  std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(generated);

  std::vector<double> data{1.5, 0.0, -2.5,
                           std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN(),
                           std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()};

  generate_output(sink, data);

  std::cout << generated << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The above code defines a grammar that, when fed with the test data, produces the output

`1.5, 0.0, -2.5, nan, inf`

However, the output that I want is

`1.5, 0.0, -2.5, special, special`

If I replace the `value` part of the grammar with

```
  value
    = (&karma::double_(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()) <<
       karma::lit("special"))
    | (&karma::double_(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()) <<
       karma::lit("special"))
    | (karma::double_)
    ;
```

I get the desired behavior for infinity.  However, I do not get the desired result for NaN since NaN has the property that (NaN != NaN) in comparisons.  So I need a way to use the fpclassify macros/functions such as isfinite().

I should be able to get what I want by replacing the `value` part of the grammar with

```
  value
    = (karma::eps(...) << karma::lit("special"))
    | (karma::double_)
    ;
```

However, every combination of function calls, function pointers, and bind incantations that I've tried for the `...` part has resulted in compiler errors.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Sehe provided an excellent general solution (which I have accepted).  Thank you!

For my particular use case, I was able to further simplify sehe's answer and wanted to document that here for others.

After changing all of the includes from `<boost/spirit/home/*>` to `<boost/spirit/include/*>` and defining `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3` before those includes, I added the following line

```
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(bool, isfinite_, std::isfinite, 1)
```

and changed the `value` part of the grammar to this

```
  value
    %= karma::double_[karma::_pass = isfinite_(karma::_1)]
    |  karma::lit("special")
    ;
```

Comment: Excellent question exposition. I'd love for all the question to be introduced in this way. Help is underway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the semantic action to dynamically "fail" the `double_` generator:

```
  value
    %= karma::double_ [ karma::_pass = !(isnan_(karma::_1) || isinf_(karma::_1)) ] 
     | karma::lit("special")
     ;
```

Now, how do we get `isnan_` and `isinf_` implemented? I prefer to use Phoenix V3 (which will be the default in all coming releases of Boost):

```
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(bool, isnan_, std::isnan, 1)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(bool, isinf_, std::isinf, 1)
```

That's all. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12fd947342f67fe2)**

Notes

- use `%=` to get automatic attribute propagation even though there is a semantic action
- include `include/*.hpp` instead of `home/*.hpp`

Full Listing:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(bool, isnan_, std::isnan, 1)
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(bool, isinf_, std::isinf, 1)

template<typename OutputIterator_T>
struct Test_Grammar :
  boost::spirit::karma::grammar<OutputIterator_T, std::vector<double>()>
{
  Test_Grammar() : Test_Grammar::base_type(start), start(), value()
    {
      namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
      namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

      start
        = *(value % karma::lit(", "))
        ;

      value
        %= karma::double_ [ karma::_pass = !(isnan_(karma::_1) || isinf_(karma::_1)) ] 
         | karma::lit("special")
         ;
    }

  boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator_T, std::vector<double>()> start;
  boost::spirit::karma::rule<OutputIterator_T, double()> value;
};

template <typename OutputIterator_T>
bool generate_output(OutputIterator_T& sink, std::vector<double> const& data)
{
    Test_Grammar<OutputIterator_T> grammar;
    return (boost::spirit::karma::generate(sink, grammar, data));
}

int main (int, char**)
{
  std::string generated;
  std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> sink(generated);

  std::vector<double> data{1.5, 0.0, -2.5,
                           std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN(),
                           std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()};

  generate_output(sink, data);

  std::cout << generated << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1.5, 0.0, -2.5, special, special
```

Comment: Note a farily similar question arose earlier which I've solved with another technique that you might find interesting: **[A: Boost Karma - non consuming predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079143/boost-karma-non-consuming-predicate/23080311#23080311)**